# Grist: lookup value from another table

Tags: python, grist

Attempting to learn Grist, and don't know Python...but willing to learn. Just trying to draw the lines between Python and formulas.

I have a table that has "Items": fields named "ProductID" "collection" & "buyer"
There is another table that is named "Sales": fields named "Sku"(same as ProductID) "Qty" "Cost" "Sales" "Date"

I would like to create another table, that consolidates the data into one document (since all of sales may not be in all of items, and sales has a ton of duplicates due to the date the transaction occurred.)

Something like: "Sku" "Buyer" "collection" "Qty" "Cost" "Sales" "margin"(formula to calculate)
"Sales" would need to be the root table, and reference the "items" table for more information.

If my data was smaller, in excel I would:

copy skus, paste in new tab, remove duplicates, and run a sumifs.
ex: if in cell B1 and sku is in a1:

=Sumifs(sales!$Qty, sales!$sku, A1)

Then I would run an index match on items in c1 for example:

=index(items!$Buyer, match(a1, Items!$ProductID, 0), 1)

Answer (score 1):

(Very late, but answering in case it helps others.)

It sounds like the resulting table should have one record per Sku (aka ProductId). You can do it in two ways: as another view of the `Items` table or as a summary of the `Sales` table grouped by Sku.

In either case, you can pull in the sum of Qty or Cost as needed.

In case of a summary table, such sums get included automatically (more on that in https://support.getgrist.com/summary-tables/#summary-formulas).

If you base it on the `Items` table, you can look up relevant Sales records by adding a formula column (e.g. named `sales`) with formula:

```
Sales.lookupRecords(Sku=$ProductID)
```

Then you can easily add sums of Qty and Cost as columns with formulas like `SUM($sales.Qty)` or `SUM($sales.Cost)`.